# LinearSVC: Equation of a straight line that separates two classes from a scatterplot graph and pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a straight line that separates two classes. I'm using panda's dataframe with scatterplot.

Here is my code before I get you into my problem:

Libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from scipy.io import arff
```

Data:

```
arquivo_arff = arff.loadarff(r"/content/Rice_MSC_Dataset.arff")
dados = pd.DataFrame(arquivo_arff[0])
```

Filter:

```
dados = dados[['MINOR_AXIS', 'MAJOR_AXIS', 'CLASS']]
```

Another filter:

```
dados = dados[dados['CLASS'].isin([b"Arborio", b"Ipsala"])]
```

Graph with two parameters:

```
sns.scatterplot(
    data=dados, 
    x="MINOR_AXIS", 
    y="MAJOR_AXIS", 
    hue="CLASS")
plt.show()
```

My problem is here, when I use LinearSVC for finding que parameters and coeficients of my equation:

```
model = LinearSVC()
model.fit(dados.drop('CLASS', axis=1), dados['CLASS'])

a, b = model.coef_[0]
d = model.intercept_[0]

print('a:', a)
print('b:', b)
print('d:', d)
```

`You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.`

I didn't understand that error quite well. Is there any ways that I can fix this in my code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The error is pretty clear, the format for your targets is not supported by the model, and it suggests using sklearn's multilabelbinarizer to transform your target into something that the model can use.

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes, I saw that. My problem is that I'm a first period engineer student... My professor just sent us this.. We all have zero experience with coding and I'm kinda trying to do this alone. I've done a great progress, but I tried to google it about this "MultiLabelBinarizer" and found nothing that could help me. I've tried to do this `model = MultiLabelBinarizer(LinearSVC())` but i think i'm very wrong. I'm not asking for the final answer. If you could just help me to find some materials to study I would apreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: In general, it might be worth asking the professor to go over a standard machine learning workflow with the class, or to find a general ML tutorial to follow until you get an understanding (assuming this is going to continue to be a focus for the course)

Comment: Thank You for your advice. I might try this. Our subject is Algebra... I cannot see the link between this two things.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for multilabelbinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) have some good examples for specific use, but a general workflow for sklearn transformers is:

Split data into features and labels

```
X = dados.drop('CLASS', axis=1)
y = dados['CLASS']

#optionally, use train_test_split to split data into training and validation sets
#X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y)
```

Do transformations on input and target data

```
mb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mb.fit(y)
mb.transform(y)
#can also be done in one step with mb.fit_transform(y)
#if using train_test_split: mb.fit_transform(y_train); mb.transform(y_test)
```

Fit your model

```
model = LinearSVC()
model.fit(X,y) #or model.fit(X_train,y_train) if using training and validation sets
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error